# What's the most effective way to interpolate between two colors? (pseudocode and bitwise ops expected)

Tags: colors, hex, interpolation

Making a Blackberry app, want a Gradient class. What's the most effective way (as in, speed and battery life) to interpolate two colors? Please be specific.

```java
// Java, of course
int c1 = 0xFFAA0055   // color 1, ARGB
int c2 = 0xFF00CCFF   // color 2, ARGB
float st = 0          // the current step in the interpolation, between 0 and 1
```

Help from here on. 
Should I separate each channel of each color, convert them to decimal and interpolate?  Is there a simpler way?

```java
interpolatedChannel = red1+((red2-red1)*st)
interpolatedChannel = interpolatedChannel.toString(16)
```

^ Is this the right thing to do? If speed and effectiveness 
is important in a mobile    app, should I use bitwise operations?

Help me!

Comment: Any reason that you're not using java's Color class?

Answer (score 10):

You'll have to separate channels, but there's no need to convert them to decimal.

For example, if you allow 256 possible gradients:

```c
red = red1 + ((red2 - red1) * stage / 256)
```

EDIT: Since you said you don't know much about bit management, here's a quick way to split channels:

```c
red = color & 0x000000ff;
green = color & 0x0000ff00;
blue = color & 0x00ff0000;
alpha = color >> 24;
```

And combining them back:

```c
color = (alpha << 24) | blue | green | red;
```

From here, the details should normally be handled by the compiler optimizations.  If anything, you're looking for the best algorithm.

Comment: So how do I separate the channels? Back when I did actionscript, once I needed to do it. I turned the hex value into a string, separated the string into 2 character components, and turned each component back into an integer. I'm sure this is a lousy way of doing it, so please help me here.
Also, I need to know if that formula is the best idea or if bitwise ops are faster/better.

Comment: You shouldn't need to convert hex into a string to separate it.  The only recommendation is to take a look at bitwise operators for the language, which are usually "&", "|", "^", "<<" and ">>".

Comment: you do want to mask the interpolated channels before combining back. the division used to compute the green channel would pollute the red channel with the green remainder (e.g.) otherwise.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Now I have the separate channels, but I still need the interpolation thing. Help?

Comment: I did... I just thought there was a way of doing that formula with bitwise operations, and that doing so would be faster. Am I right?

Comment: Wait a second... are you confusing the red and blue channels?

Comment: @navand: no you're not right. interpolation is inherently an arithmetic operation. What makes you think bit-wise operation would be faster than arithmetic operations that are natively supported by most processors ? do you really want to implement a multiplier ?

Answer (score 8):

```as
private function interpolateColorsCompact( a:int, b:int, lerp:Number ):int
{ 
   var MASK1:int = 0xff00ff; 
   var MASK2:int = 0x00ff00; 

   var f2:int = 256 * lerp;
   var f1:int = 256 - f2;

   return   ((((( a & MASK1 ) * f1 ) + ( ( b & MASK1 ) * f2 )) >> 8 ) & MASK1 ) 
          | ((((( a & MASK2 ) * f1 ) + ( ( b & MASK2 ) * f2 )) >> 8 ) & MASK2 );

}
```

Not sure if this is the most compact way of doing it, but it uses less local variables and less operators than the classic method that splis them into 3 channels first.

Oh - and sorry that this is Actionscript, but it should be clear how to convert this to Java.

Comment: I don't know how this bitmagic works, but if you change mask2 to 0xFF00FF00 (leave everything else unchanged) it will linearly interpolate the alpha between a and b as well (assuming ARGB)

Comment: Working well for me. Would like to understand what's happening here a bit better though.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated my answer (found a better way):**

The following technique will **lose 1 bit precision** per channel, but it's extremely fast, since you won't have to split the colors into channels:

```c
int color1 = ...;
int color2 = ...;
int interpolatedColor = ((color1 & 0xFEFEFEFE) >> 1) + 
                        ((color2 & 0xFEFEFEFE) >> 1));
```

So, first you ***AND*** both colors by `0xFEFEFEFE`. This removes the last bit per channel (reduces precision, as I said). After that, you can safely divide the entire value by 2 (implemented as a right-shift by 1). Finally, you just add up the two values.

Comment: The question said pseudocode and bitwise ops expected. I don't know a thing about bit managing. Examples!

Comment: This only gives a 50/50 mix, not a configurable 0..1 blend.

Comment: @Jason: Oh, I didn't realize that! You're right... I'll change my answer to community wiki. Maybe it's still useful to somebody...

Comment: Yeah not exactly what I need. If you find something, please help!

Comment: Was this ported from Amiga demos?

Answer (score 0):

Just the java version of /u/Quasimondo's answer:

```
public static int mixColors(int a, int b, float ratio){
    int mask1 = 0x00ff00ff;
    int mask2 = 0xff00ff00;

    int f2 = (int)(256 * ratio);
    int f1 = 256 - f2;

    return (((((a & mask1) * f1) + ((b & mask1) * f2)) >> 8) & mask1) 
         | (((((a & mask2) * f1) + ((b & mask2) * f2)) >> 8) & mask2);
}
```

If you only need exact 50/50 ratios you can cut out the bitshifting:

```
public static int mixColors(int a, int b){
    int mask1 = 0x00ff00ff;
    int mask2 = 0xff00ff00;

    return (((a & mask1) + (b & mask1)) & mask1) 
         | (((a & mask2) + (b & mask2)) & mask2);
}
```