# How to mix two int colors correctly

Tags: java, colors, int, bit-manipulation, color-blending

I'm trying to blend two colors that are coded as integers. Here is my little function:

```
int blend (int a, int b, float ratio) {
    if (ratio > 1f) {
        ratio = 1f;
    } else if (ratio < 0f) {
        ratio = 0f;
    }
    float iRatio = 1.0f - ratio;

    int aA = (a >> 24 & 0xff);
    int aR = ((a & 0xff0000) >> 16);
    int aG = ((a & 0xff00) >> 8);
    int aB = (a & 0xff);

    int bA = (b >> 24 & 0xff);
    int bR = ((b & 0xff0000) >> 16);
    int bG = ((b & 0xff00) >> 8);
    int bB = (b & 0xff);

    int A = ((int)(aA * iRatio) + (int)(bA * ratio));
    int R = ((int)(aR * iRatio) + (int)(bR * ratio));
    int G = ((int)(aG * iRatio) + (int)(bG * ratio));
    int B = ((int)(aB * iRatio) + (int)(bB * ratio));

    return A << 24 | R << 16 | G << 8 | B;
}
```

Everything seems to work fine, but certain arguments produce wrong colors.
For example:

```
    int a = 0xbbccdd;
    int b = 0xbbccdd;
    int c = blend(a, b, 0.5f); // gives 0xbaccdc, although it should be 0xbbccdd
```

My guess is that either multiplication by float ratios or casting are to blame here, but I can't figure out what's wrong with them...

So what's the correct way to blend two colors in java?

Comment: so why don't you use `ByteBuffer` for getting `byte[]` array, and generating int value from a `byte[]` array?

Comment: For performance. Correct me if I'm wrong, but creating primitives is way faster than instantiating objects. This code has to run several hundred times per sec.

Comment: The best answer I've found using bitwise ops is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4787257/303612

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that the casting to int should be done after the addition. Like this

```
int a = (int)((aA * iRatio) + (bA * ratio));
```

I would also suggest using Java naming conventions when using variables. Only constants should be caps.

Comment: It helped. Stupid me, why didn't I cast like that :/

Comment: BTW. how would you name the variables? I know caps are for final static variables only, this is just SOOOO readable and locigal...

Comment: Maybe something like ´redHex´, ´greenHex´ and ´blueHex´ since they represent the hex value of the respective colors. :)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks JuliusB and dARKpRINCE.  I've adapted it to accept java.awt.Color, fixed the cast and renamed the variables somewhat more like the Java standard.  It works well.  Thanks again!

```
Color blend( Color c1, Color c2, float ratio ) {
    if ( ratio > 1f ) ratio = 1f;
    else if ( ratio < 0f ) ratio = 0f;
    float iRatio = 1.0f - ratio;

    int i1 = c1.getRGB();
    int i2 = c2.getRGB();

    int a1 = (i1 >> 24 & 0xff);
    int r1 = ((i1 & 0xff0000) >> 16);
    int g1 = ((i1 & 0xff00) >> 8);
    int b1 = (i1 & 0xff);

    int a2 = (i2 >> 24 & 0xff);
    int r2 = ((i2 & 0xff0000) >> 16);
    int g2 = ((i2 & 0xff00) >> 8);
    int b2 = (i2 & 0xff);

    int a = (int)((a1 * iRatio) + (a2 * ratio));
    int r = (int)((r1 * iRatio) + (r2 * ratio));
    int g = (int)((g1 * iRatio) + (g2 * ratio));
    int b = (int)((b1 * iRatio) + (b2 * ratio));

    return new Color( a << 24 | r << 16 | g << 8 | b );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks JuliusB, dARKpRINCE and bmauter.
Based on your input I've created the following function which blends n Colors with equal ratio:

```
public static Color blend(Color... c) {
    if (c == null || c.length <= 0) {
        return null;
    }
    float ratio = 1f / ((float) c.length);

    int a = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int g = 0;
    int b = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        int rgb = c[i].getRGB();
        int a1 = (rgb >> 24 & 0xff);
        int r1 = ((rgb & 0xff0000) >> 16);
        int g1 = ((rgb & 0xff00) >> 8);
        int b1 = (rgb & 0xff);
        a += ((int) a1 * ratio);
        r += ((int) r1 * ratio);
        g += ((int) g1 * ratio);
        b += ((int) b1 * ratio);
    }

    return new Color(a << 24 | r << 16 | g << 8 | b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@dARKpRINCE's answer is correct, but I have a few minor tips:

1. Your function should be static, since it doesn't depend on any object fields.
2. You can save one operation when extracting a color's alpha component by doing `x >>> 24` instead of `(x >> 24) & 0xFF`.
3. Anything of the form:

   ```
   (a * (1 - ratio)) + (b * ratio)
   ```

   can be written as:

   ```
   a + (b - a) * ratio
   ```

   which halves the number of multiplications you need.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer might be:

```
public static Color mixColors(Color... colors) {
    float ratio = 1f / ((float) colors.length);
    int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0, a = 0;
    for (Color color : colors) {
        r += color.getRed() * ratio;
        g += color.getGreen() * ratio;
        b += color.getBlue() * ratio;
        a += color.getAlpha() * ratio;
    }
    return new Color(r, g, b, a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested in blending colors in LibGDX (based on the solution above, but tailored for LibGDX API):

```
static Color blend( Color c1, Color c2, float ratio ) {
    if ( ratio > 1f ) ratio = 1f;
    else if ( ratio < 0f ) ratio = 0f;
    float iRatio = 1.0f - ratio;

    int i1 = Color.argb8888(c1);
    int i2 = Color.argb8888(c2);

    int a1 = (i1 >> 24 & 0xff);
    int r1 = ((i1 & 0xff0000) >> 16);
    int g1 = ((i1 & 0xff00) >> 8);
    int b1 = (i1 & 0xff);

    int a2 = (i2 >> 24 & 0xff);
    int r2 = ((i2 & 0xff0000) >> 16);
    int g2 = ((i2 & 0xff00) >> 8);
    int b2 = (i2 & 0xff);

    int a = (int)((a1 * iRatio) + (a2 * ratio));
    int r = (int)((r1 * iRatio) + (r2 * ratio));
    int g = (int)((g1 * iRatio) + (g2 * ratio));
    int b = (int)((b1 * iRatio) + (b2 * ratio));

    return new Color(r << 24 | g << 16 | b << 8 | a);
}
```