# How to do ARGB color interpolation without separating components?

Tags: java, interpolation, argb

After trying and failing to figure this out myself, I have scavenged some code which should combine two colors (integers) by a specified fraction from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630925/whats-the-most-effective-way-to-interpolate-between-two-colors-pseudocode-and), but I am just simply not crafty enough to get it working with ARGB integers.
Does anyone know how to convert this function from combining RGB to combining ARGB?

```
public static int mixColors(int a, int b, float fractionB){ 
   int mask1 = 0xff00ff; 
   int mask2 = 0x00ff00; 
    
   int f2 = (int)(256 * fractionB);
   int f1 = 256 - f2;
   
   return   ((((( a & mask1 ) * f1 ) + ( ( b & mask1 ) * f2 )) >>> 8 ) & mask1 ) 
          | ((((( a & mask2 ) * f1 ) + ( ( b & mask2 ) * f2 )) >>> 8 ) & mask2 );
}
```

I have tried setting the masks to `mask1 = 0x00ff00ff; mask2 = 0xff00ff00;` but the function still only outputs a 3 byte number.

Comment: this algorithm is basically multiplying the colors by 256, that is, the value is shifted 8 bits left - since using `int` the 4th byte is lost - you can use `long` in the calculation (mask and factors) to avoid that

Comment: Thank you @user16320675! That did the trick! I can't believe I didn't think of that... Guess I was just blinded by the binary arithmetic that I can't justify in my head. Unfortunately, I don't know how to credit you, as your answer is just a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "...since using int the 4th byte is lost - you can use long in the calculation (mask and factors) to avoid that" - user16320675

Thank you! I should have thought of that, but I guess that's what they all say.
Here are the updated functions for 32bit integer ARGB color values:

```
public static int mixColors(int a, int b){
    long mask1 = 0x00ff00ffL;
    long mask2 = 0xff00ff00L;

    return (int)((((((a & mask1) + (b & mask1)) * 128) >> 8) & mask1) 
               | (((((a & mask2) + (b & mask2)) * 128) >> 8) & mask2));
}

public static int mixColors(int a, int b, float fractionB){
    long mask1 = 0x00ff00ffL;
    long mask2 = 0xff00ff00L;

    short f2 = (short)(256 * fractionB),
          f1 = (short)(256 - f2);
          
    return (int)((((((a & mask1) * f1) + ((b & mask1) * f2)) >> 8) & mask1) 
               | (((((a & mask2) * f1) + ((b & mask2) * f2)) >> 8) & mask2));
}
```

Comment: @user16320675, Oh. Yeah, I didn't properly convert the literals. Thanks for paying this level of attention. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer above works only if the representation of ARGB is 'premultiplied' (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) - otherwise, interpolation will assign too much weight to non-opaque colors. (For example, if one of the colors has alpha = 0 (invisible), the 50/50 interpolation will still colorize the result using 50% of that invisible color).

For 'straight' (non-premultiplied) ARGB, one must first calculate the interpolated alpha (equal to a_alpha * f1 + b_alpha * f2), and then separately the RGB part, using adjusted interpolation coefficients. C++ code below (should be easy enough to convert to Java):

```cpp
// Interpolates between the two colors using the specified `fraction`, in the
// 0-256 range. 0 means result = c1; 256 means result = c2; 128 means 50/50.
inline Color InterpolateColors(Color c1, Color c2, int16_t fraction) {
  int16_t f2 = fraction;
  int16_t f1 = 256 - fraction;
  uint16_t c1_a = c1.a();
  uint16_t c2_a = c2.a();
  uint32_t a_mult = (c1_a * f1 + c2_a * f2);
  uint32_t a = a_mult / 256;
  if (c1_a == c2_a) {
    // Common case, e.g. both colors opaque. Leave fractions as-is.
  } else if (c1_a == 0) {
    f1 = 0;
    f2 = 256;
  } else if (c2_a == 0) {
    f1 = 256;
    f2 = 0;
  } else {
    f2 = (uint32_t)256 * f2 * c2_a / a_mult;
    f1 = 256 - f2;
  }

  uint32_t mask1 = 0x00FF00FF;
  uint32_t mask2 = 0x0000FF00;
  uint32_t rgb =
      (((((c1.asArgb() & mask1) * f1) + ((c2.asArgb() & mask1) * f2)) / 256) &
       mask1) |
      (((((c1.asArgb() & mask2) * f1) + ((c2.asArgb() & mask2) * f2)) / 256) &
       mask2);
  return Color(a << 24 | rgb);
}
```